# Entity Framework Core 2.0 How to automatically Insert Update Delete an detached entity

Tags: c#, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, ef-core-2.0

I have found a lot of threads discussing this topic but none of them have a good solution or I'm just not able to use better search tags :|

I have a Angular2 Frontend with a ASP.Net Core WebApi2 Backend. The database is connected via Entity Framework Core 2.

My issue is just focussed on the backend with EF Core.
My aim is to have a simple method which takes a detached entity (coming from the frontend) which should be updated to the database.

The entity itself has some properties with a lot of navigation properties and these navigation properties have also a lot of navigation properties.

The database model could look like this:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {
        DocumentNavigation = new HashSet<Document>();
    }

    public string ProjectNr { get; set; }
    public string ProjectTitle { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> DocumentNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        UserNavigation = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> UserNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

My method looks like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("{projectNr}")]
public IActionResult UpdateProject(string projectNr, [FromBody]Project project)
{
      using (abcContext ctx = new abcContext())
      {
            DoSomething();

            ctx.SaveChanges();
      }

      return NoContent();
 }
```

How do I have to write the method "DoSomething()" in order to deal with this problem?

Imagine, my new object "project" could have new documents, some documents which are still in the database should be deleted because they are no longer in the parameter object "project" and some documents have just changed its normal propoerties like "DocumentName". This could also has happend to the underlaying UserNavigations ...

I just wanted to keep this sample simple. My original entities and the database is much bigger.

To my mind the EF should have a method like "ctx.Update(project)" which manages all these problems???
I cannot believe that I have to do all this stuff manually.

But just in case of doing it manually, how would it look like?

Thanks very much for your support.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities

Comment: Until you can show you own attempts at writing `DoSomething()` and indicate where you're stuck this question is too broad (basically you're asking us to write your method).

Comment: Thanks Ivan ... I think your link will answer all of my questions. In the end I will have to do it by my own manually... but the documentation describes a scenario with insert update delete of an entity with its navigation properties. Perfect!!!